# Matlab: how to read binary numbers from a file?

Tags: file, matlab, math, binary, string-formatting

**File has binary numbers separated by newline.**

```
$ cat bin_MCS.txt |tail
000000001100000000000010000000000
000000010010000000000010000000000
000011000000000000000000000000000
000010100000000000000000000000000
000101000000000000000000000000000
000100100000000000000000000000000
000100001000000000000010000000000
000000110000000000000010000000000
000001010000000000000010000000000
000010001000000000000010000000000
```

**Matlab reads the binary numbers in DEC, wrong**

```
>> textread('bin_MCS.txt')

ans =

   1.0e+30 *

    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
```

**Goal**

> I need to read the binary numbers to a matrix like this [1 0 1;0 1 1]. The first puzzle is to be able to read the binary numbers. Then the next puzzle is to be able to read them in a certain format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly convoluted, but personal favorite of mine:

```
>> (char(textread('bin_MCS.txt','%s'))-'0') * pow2(32:-1:0).'
ans =
    25166848
    37749760
   402653184
   335544320
   671088640
   603979776
   553649152
   100664320
   167773184
   285213696
```

If you use `textscan`, it'll even be faster than the `bin2dec` version:

```
tic
for ii = 1:1e3

    fid = fopen('bin_MCS.txt', 'r');
        C = textscan(fid,'%s');
    fclose(fid);

    R = (char(C{1})-'0') * pow2(32:-1:0).';

end
toc


tic
for ii = 1:1e3
    bin2dec(textread('bin_MCS.txt','%s'));
end
toc
```

Results:

```
Elapsed time is 0.182339 seconds.
Elapsed time is 15.600509 seconds.
```

Granted, this is not a completely fair test, but at least it illustrates that there is a substantial difference.

Comment: I can understand this far `(char(textread('bin_MCS.txt','%s')))` but `-'0')` breaks up the thing nicely, why?

Comment: @hhh: subtracting `'0'` basically equals subtracting 48, the ASCII code for `'0'`. The subtraction will result in an array containing zeros and ones in all the right places (instead of `48` and `49` it used to be); basically, it is an ugly but very efficient conversion from strings to numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Read as strings an then convert to decimal numbers with [`bin2dec`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bin2dec.html):

```
bin2dec(textread('bin_MCS.txt','%s'))

ans =

    25166848
    37749760
   402653184
   335544320
   671088640
   603979776
   553649152
   100664320
   167773184
   285213696
```

EDIT:

To read the individual binary digits into a matrix, you can use this (48 is the ASCII code for '0'):

```
cell2mat(textread('bin_MCS.txt','%s'))-48
```

Comment: My answer came too late, but the link to the [bin2dec function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bin2dec.html) should be helpful.

Comment: You should have explained what you want do do with the binary numbers... Maybe you can do it directly on the (binary) strings

Comment: @hhh See my edit. Perhaps you should also update your question for clarity

Comment: Roger updated. Thank you. Can you explain the cell2mat? The other answer use the same logic with char.

Comment: @hhh: `char` is specific to cell strings, `cell2mat` is more generic; it will convert *any* convertible cell into a matrix (but it is slower in this case).